# Calculate total of two values in ListBoxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have two `ListBoxes` in a WPF application with school courses and fees. However, when run, the label I have that's supposed to show the total of two values only shows the most recently selected value. How can I make it so that the total actually calculates the two selected values?

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="courseListBox" SelectionChanged="courseListBox_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="126" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="42,35,0,0">
        <ListBoxItem>Intro to Comp Sci</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Honors Comp Sci</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>AP Comp Sci A</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>AP Comp Sci P</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Independent Study</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Webpage Design</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox x:Name="classListBox" SelectionChanged="classListBox_SelectionChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="85" Margin="42,197,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <ListBoxItem>Freshman</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Sophomore</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Junior</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Senior</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <Label x:Name="totalLabel" Content="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="168,34,0,0"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="42,9,0,0"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="42,169,0,0"/>

</Grid>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public int courseFee = 0;
    public int classFee = 0;
    public int totalCost = 0;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void courseListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selected = courseListBox.SelectedIndex;
        if (selected == 0)
            classFee = 545;
        if (selected == 1)
            classFee = 615;
        if (selected == 2)
            classFee = 1500;
        if (selected == 3)
            classFee = 1000;
        if (selected == 4)
            classFee = 2500;
        if (selected == 5)
            classFee = 1720;
        totalCost = courseFee + classFee;
        totalLabel.Content = totalCost;
    }

    private void classListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selected = classListBox.SelectedIndex;
        if (selected == 0)
            classFee = 350;
        if (selected == 1)
            classFee = 275;
        if (selected == 2)
            classFee = 200;
        if (selected == 3)
            classFee = 150;
        totalCost = courseFee + classFee;
        totalLabel.Content = totalCost;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change "classFee" in courseListBox_SelectionChanged to "courseFee"

Answer (score 0):

The server is stateless, so you cannot remember the value of fees between postbacks.  Just combine the two procedures.

```
protected void getTotal() 
    {
        int selected = courseListBox.SelectedIndex;
        if (selected == 0)
            classFee = 545;
        if (selected == 1)
            classFee = 615;
        if (selected == 2)
            classFee = 1500;
        if (selected == 3)
            classFee = 1000;
        if (selected == 4)
            classFee = 2500;
        if (selected == 5)
            classFee = 1720;
        int total = classFee;
        selected = classListBox.SelectedIndex;
        if (selected == 0)
            classFee = 350;
        if (selected == 1)
            classFee = 275;
        if (selected == 2)
            classFee = 200;
        if (selected == 3)
            classFee = 150;
        total += classFee;
        totalLabel.Content = total;
    }

    private void classListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       getTotal();
    }
```

(make both listboxes use the same event handler)

Comment: This is a WPF application. What's your mean by *server* ?

Answer (score 0):

Well to start probably a good idea to change your classFee in courseListBox_SelectionChanged method to courseFree

Code would probably be something like this...

```
int value = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                value += int.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[e.Column].Text);
            }

            textBox1.Text = value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant course fee and not a classFee in courseListBox_SelectionChanged like this

```
private void courseListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selected = courseListBox.SelectedIndex;
        if (selected == 0)
            courseFee = 545;
        if (selected == 1)
            courseFee = 615;
        if (selected == 2)
            courseFee = 1500;
        if (selected == 3)
            courseFee = 1000;
        if (selected == 4)
            courseFee = 2500;
        if (selected == 5)
            courseFee = 1720;
        totalCost = courseFee + classFee;
        totalLabel.Content = totalCost;
    }
```